# Bootstrap 4 how to make 'media object' responsive

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, media-queries

I've got a media object so I can have an image with some text next to it, and it works on large screens. The problem comes when I go to a smaller screen the text gets pushed of the screen and images become slightly different sized and some are moved slightly to the left or right.

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
      <li class="media">
        <img
          src="image.jpg"
          class="align-self-center mr-3"
          alt="..."
          style="width: 277.5px; height: 220px"
        />
        <div class="media-body">
          <h5 class="mt-0">Suspendisse potenti. Quisque mattis.</h5>
          <p class="pb-5">
            Mauris tincidunt pellentesque risus, accumsan.
          </p>
          <p>1 hour • $9999</p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="media my-4">
        <img
          src="images.jpg"
          class="align-self-center mr-3"
          alt="..."
          style="width: 277.5px; height: 220px"
        />
        <div class="media-body">
          <h5 class="mt-0 mb-1 align-self-center">
            Sed congue rhoncus interdum.
          </h5>
          <p class="pb-5">
            Ut euismod erat eget pharetra.
          </p>
          <p>1 hour • $9999</p>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

I'm working with something like this with about 4 more images. Is there a way through bootstrap itself or through media queries that I can make it on the small screen have the images scale down to about 50px x 50px?

Thank you for any help in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the class `image-fluid` for your image. As shown in the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/images/).

> `<img src="..." class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">`

Comment: This didn't do anything for me. It looks fine if I shrink the viewport on the pc but when i look at it on mobile it is still messed up with every second image being wider. I even tried to add some media query to the ```img-fluid``` but still nothing there.